# Parametric dataannotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

is there a way to parametrize the minumum length in the StringLength dataannotation?

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Language),ErrorMessageResourceName = "Delivery_ZIPRequired")]
    [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Language), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Address_ZipInvalidLength")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _parametrize_?

Comment: I mean having that "5" replaced by the value of another model property value. Ex. Model.ZipLength

Comment: No that is not possible. Attributes are metadata and the arguments must be known at compile time (e.g. a `const`). You can solve this by creating a custom conditional validation attribute (where one of the arguments is the name of the other property)